# Mapbox Display Lat and Lng and Zoom then putting them inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, coordinates, mapbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTDs6.png)

I was wondering how to actually get the lat and lng and zoom values like in the picture example on mapbox style builder not with a mouse click or with a mouse move, just the entire map inside a div.

So explaining in detail, I was wondering if there was a way to grab the maps coordinates and display them based off of what mapbox does in there studio editor. They calculate the lat and lng and zoom level of their whole map and when a user scrolls around the map the lat and lng changes and it displays the new coordinates with the zoom level. I need to take those values and place them inside a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You have several samples on  this.

[how to get the coords of a point](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-point/)
[how to create a draggable marker](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-marker/)
[how to get the coords of cursor](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mouse-position/)

If you need the zoom too, you only need to add [`map.getZoom()`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#getzoom) to he methods that are painting the `lngLat.lng` and `lngLat.lat`

Comment: Yes, Ive taken these examples and tried to make something similar but I couldn't get the coordinates based off of the whole map locations like Map box studios does in the example.

Comment: But those samples show exactly what you asked for, what have you coded so far?

Comment: map.on('mousemove', function() {

        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
          // e.point is the x, y coordinates of the mousemove event relative
          // to the top-left corner of the map

          // e.lngLat is the longitude, latitude geographical position of the event
          map.getCenter().lngLat;
        map.getZoom();
      });
I'm trying to get the lat and lng to display on the center of the map itself not a click or mouse move.

Comment: For that you only need to use `var center = map.getCenter();`